# How do I stop Mercurial's "hg serve -d" service under Windows?

Tags: windows-services, mercurial

I'm technically savvy but don't have extensive experience with servers/daemons (I'm a Windows guy, so...command lines intimidate me).

I started a Mercurial server using the hg serve -d command, and all was well.

Now, I want to stop it, and can't find a process to kill.  Does anybody know the process name or a relatively simply CLI command to get it done?

Comment: I ran into the same issue and running a "netstat -p tcp -ano" command gave me the process Id that was using the port the server was running on, the process was "thgw.exe". I then used the Windows Process Explorer to end the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a link to stop and start the Mercurial server via command line
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/hgserve

The information you're looking for is at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can choice one of below ways:

1: You must enter Processes tab in Window Task Manager and try to kill process which names hg.exe, its description is Mecurial Distributed SCM.
Note: I sent ps -W | grep hg to cygwin to find it. Hope this way can help you

[image]

2: Another way, you can using ToitorseHg to start and stop server instead using command line hg serve

[ Open ToitorseHg -> Repository -> Web Server ]

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Did you try accessing the "Services" GUI? Not sure if  mercurial shows up there, but its worth a try...

Start -> Administrative Tools -> Services

If Administrative Tools does not show up, right click the taskbar, click properties, click "start Menu" and customize. Then check "Show Administrative Tools". This is from memory since our IT department prevents us average users from doing this :-)

Good luck